# Bool returns different value when referenced in other scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm checking for internet connection using the following script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckInternets : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string url = "some photo on my google drive";
    private string wwww;

    public static bool InternetON = false; 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {        
        StartCoroutine(CheckConnection());
    }

    IEnumerator CheckConnection()
    {
        var www = new WWW(url);

        yield return www;

        if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded > 0)
        {
            InternetON = true;
            Debug.Log("MAIN Script Check :: Online! :)");                        
        }

        if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded == 0)
        {
            InternetON = false;
            Debug.LogWarning("MAIN Script Check :: Offline! :(");
        }
    }
}
```

Tried this on my (Android) phone, connected to Mobile data (having none), it works just fine.

Issues kick in once I reference that `InternetON` bool in other scripts, i.e. said scripts always read it as `false` (or `true` if I set it to thatin CheckInternets.cs), so my hunch is that I'm referencing it wrong, or I'm not using the bool properly, but can't figure it out how.

Other scripts example:

```
void Start()
{        
    if (CheckInternets.InternetON)
    {
        //do some stuff
        Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Online! :)");
    }
    else
    {
        //do some other stuff
        Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Offline! :(");
    }
}
```

In this case, if I'm online, my Console will read:

- OTHER Script Check :: Offline! :(
- MAIN Script Check :: Online! :)

If I'm offline, it will say Offline for both of them.

Any advice? Cheers!

Comment: If that's the order of the logging, and it actually happens in that order, then it looks likely that the other script checks the connection before this one even tests/sets it.

Comment: Thought about that as well and put the `CheckInternets` at the top of the Script Execution Order, to no effect -- matter of fact it was the only one in the list (after the Text Mesh Pro ones, which I can't remove at all, for some reason).

Comment: You check too early from "other" script, i.e. Unity calls SomeOther.Start() method before the connection is established. You can't control how long it will take to connect by simply altering the execution order. The coroutine finishes when the connection is done no matter when the coroutine was started. That's the idea behind Unity coroutines, they span across multiple frames (or some time frame, etc).

Comment: Yeah, it was clear as I was seeing the Console log messages coming in the "wrong" order, but didn't know what exactly I could do about it. Everything seems fine now, after implementing @derHugo's solution 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartCoroutine(CheckConnection());` starts the [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in `Start()` ... **BUT** it won't be executed until it receives a [`MoveNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) call which happens **after** it received the `Update` call

From [Execution Order Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html):

> Normal coroutine updates are run after the `Update` function returns.

`Update` is not called until **all** `Start` calls of the scene finished when checking the `bool` in `Start` in your other script the `CheckConnection()` will not even have executed the first `yield`.

---

Instead you have to wait until the check finished.

Here are some ways of how you could do that using `IEnumerator Start`

 Unity allows to do so in order to delay the `Start` until something is finished ... just what you want to do:

1. **`yield` the `CheckConnection`**

   You can simply `yield return` any other `IEnumerator` in a coroutine in order to wait until that other one finished

   ```
   public class CheckInternets : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private static string url = "some photo on my google drive";
       private static string wwww;

       public static bool InternetON = false; 

       public static IEnumerator CheckConnection()
       {
           var www = new WWW(url);

           yield return www;

           if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded > 0)
           {
               InternetON = true;
               Debug.Log("MAIN Script Check :: Online! :)");                        
           }

           if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded == 0)
           {
               InternetON = false;
               Debug.LogWarning("MAIN Script Check :: Offline! :(");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       IEnumerator Start()
       {
           // starts an internet check and waits until it finished
           yield return CheckInternets.CheckConnection();

           if (CheckInternets.InternetON)
           {
               //do some stuff
               Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Online! :)");
           }
           else
           {
               //do some other stuff
               Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Offline! :(");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Addistional flag**

   Add an flag like e.g. `checkFinished` and use [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html)

   ```
   public class CheckInternets : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private string url = "some photo on my google drive";
       private wwww;

       public static bool InternetON = false;
       public static bool IsFinished = false;

       // Start is called before the first frame update
       private void Start()
       {
           StartCoroutine(CheckConnection());
       }

       public IEnumerator CheckConnection()
       {
           IsFinished = false;

           var www = new WWW(url);

           yield return www;

           if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded > 0)
           {
               InternetON = true;
               Debug.Log("MAIN Script Check :: Online! :)");
           }

           if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded == 0)
           {
               InternetON = false;
               Debug.LogWarning("MAIN Script Check :: Offline! :(");
           }

           IsFinished = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   and do

   ```
   public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private IEnumerator Start()
       {
           // starts an internet check and waits until it finished
           yield return new WaitUntil(() => CheckInternets.IsFinished);

           if (CheckInternets.InternetON)
           {
               //do some stuff
               Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Online! :)");
           }
           else
           {
               //do some other stuff
               Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Offline! :(");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Callback**

   Add a callback `Action` so you can wait for the result without using an `IEnumerator`

   ```
   public class CheckInternets : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private string url = "some photo on my google drive";
       private string wwww;

       // now you wouldn't need this anymore and could make it 
       // a local variable in the CheckConnectionRoutine
       public static bool InternetON = false;

       public void CheckConnection(Action<bool> callback)
       {
           StartCoroutine(CheckConnectionRoutine(callback));
       }

       private IEnumerator CheckConnectionRoutine(Action<bool> callback)
       {
           var www = new WWW(url);

           yield return www;

           if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded > 0)
           {
               InternetON = true;
               Debug.Log("MAIN Script Check :: Online! :)");
           }

           if (www.isDone && www.bytesDownloaded == 0)
           {
               InternetON = false;
               Debug.LogWarning("MAIN Script Check :: Offline! :(");
           }

           callback?.Invoke(InternetON);
       }
   }
   ```

   and use it either with a method

   ```
   public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private void Start()
       {
           // somehow get a reference instead of using static
           // that's always the cleaner way
           var check = FindObjectOfType<CheckInternets>();

           // starts an internet check
           check?.CheckConnection(OnConnectionCheckFinished);
       }

       private void OnConnectionCheckFinished(bool isConnected)
       {
           if (isConnected)
           {
               //do some stuff
               Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Online! :)");
           }
           else
           {
               //do some other stuff
               Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Offline! :(");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   or directly with a lambda expression

   ```
   public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private void Start()
       {
           // somehow get a reference instead of using static
           // that's always the cleaner way
           var check = FindObjectOfType<CheckInternets>();

           // starts an internet check
           check?.CheckConnection((isConnected) =>
           {
               if (isConnected)
               {
                   //do some stuff
                   Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Online! :)");
               }
               else
               {
                   //do some other stuff
                   Debug.Log("OTHER Script Check :: Offline! :(");
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I went with the first option and everything works as intended. I might try the other options in the future. Just to double check: that `if (CheckInternet.CheckInternets.InternetON)` should be `if (CheckInternets.InternetON)`, right? I mean, I did write it as `(CheckInternets.InternetON)` and everything works.

Comment: yes it should be only `CheckInternets.InternetON` .. I accidently copied your example into the new class in Unity instead of replacing the content ;)